# Calculate hash of object in Python

Tags: python, hash

I want to put BeautifulSoup's Node object into dict, and I want to override `__hash__` to provide my own hash implementation based on the node's path.

```
def __hash__(self):
    def convert_attrs(attrs):
        for k, v in attrs.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                v = tuple(v)
            yield k, v

    reverse_path = []
    node = self.node
    while node:
        node_id = (node.name,
                   tuple(convert_attrs(node.attrs)),
                   node.text)
        reverse_path.append(node_id)
        node = node.parent
    return hash(tuple(reverse_path))
```

But this will have conflict on some nodes that have exact the same path and attrs. I can use node's index in parent's children collection to construct a unique path, but it costs too much to find the index. So any good advice to implement `__hash__` on html node object? Anyway to implement hash that not based on path but still works fine?

UPDATE: Why I want to hash the node?

I want to give every node a score, so I need something as the key to put int the hash. BeautifulSoup seems to return same node with different object(I mean it create new one when access same node again), so I want to find a way to uniquely identify the node in hash.

Comment: @TimPeters I've updated my question, can you review this question again? Sorry for my awful question.

Comment: Ya, I deleted my comment after your edit - thanks!  Now you need to define what you *want* from the hash - which properties are important to you?  For example, in what way(s) would it "be bad" to simply return `id(self)`? That's a very common way to create *a* hash "good enough" for many purposes.

Comment: 'pretty sure the hash doesn't need to be perfect.  Hashes rarely are.  So if you have hash collisions, Python will dutifully use a comparison operator to disambiguate.

Comment: Please explain *why* you want your nodes to be hashable, because it does not sound like a good idea. (it is no accident you find it hard to define your hash. more often than not, such difficulty means your object should not be hashable in the first place). If you explain your motiviation, people can propose alternative approaches.

Comment: @shx2 I've updated my question with my anwser.

Comment: If you override `__hash__` you must also override `__eq__`. First decide what's the correct behavior of your `__eq__` operator. Then defining `__hash__` along the same lines should be easy.

Comment: If two nodes have the same name+attrs+text+path, what makes them get different scores? what diffrentiates them?  Can you include *that* in your `__eq__` and `__hash__`?

Comment: @shx2 I just use node's properties (such as name, attrs, text etc.) in the path, if I use node's index in the parent's children collection as part of the path, the path will be unique, but it expensive to get index, so I want to find a way to easily. I implement __eq__ by compare their hash...

Comment: *Never* implement `__eq__` by comparing hashes. Hashes have collisions.

Comment: @shx2 ok, now I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two nodes , their tags are same, attributes are same , parents are same , contents are same, but they are different, because they are sibling. I think you have to find the index if you want to distinguish them. You can use `nextSibling` or `previousSibling` , like

```
i,t = 0 , node
while t:
    t = t.previousSibling
    i += 1
```

i do not test , so i do not know the cost.